# basic measure theory question - measure on the natural numbers

Tags: lo.logic, st.statistics, it.information-theory, measure-theory

I am looking for a succinct way to describe a subset of the natural numbers which has ``measure zero" in the following sense:  Let X_1 \subset X_2 \subset .... be any strictly nesting sequence of finite subsets of natural numbers, I want to describe a subset S \subset \N which has the property that the limit of the usual counting measures applied to S restricted to X_i is zero.

I don't know that much about measure theory and am having trouble finding any measures on countable sets such as the natural numbers.  There should be a natural measure on them such that the sets I describe above have zero measure with respect to it.  Is there a name for such a natural measure on the natural numbers?

Comment: The word "measure" in this context is not the appropriate one. You are probably looking for subsets of the naturals having zero *density*, even if your definition is not the correct definition of density. In fact,  you should divide the counting measure by the size of $X_i$ before taking the $\liminf$ (or the $\limsup$). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density for more details.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I feel obliged to: this site is for mathematics approximately at a research level. Please read the faq for appropriate places to ask this type of question. 

Comment: While I agree that the question is not really suited to MO, I would at least offer some encouragement: this kind of question is both natural and good when one is trying to get to grips with notions of `size' for infinite subsets of the natural numbers. Hopefully the wikipedia link in Francesco Polizzi's comment may be of use.

Answer (score 2):

A measure, here, isn't going to work.  You can modify your idea to get near the idea of density, as Francesco pointed out.  But, since you're new with measure theory, remember that a measure is countably additive, and (assuming you do want to divide by the size of the $X_i$ in your explanation, as was suggested) you're going to get the measure of any single point to be zero.  Then by countable additivity, you're going to get the measure of any *set* to be zero.

This is why you're having trouble finding measures on countable sets; if you want small sets to be measure zero, you're going to get the zero measure, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yes this seems to be precisely why finding such a measure will fail. If one wishes to weight all natural numbers equally, then only the trivial `zero measure' can assign a finite measure to an infinite set.